# Android battery usage

Tags: android, power-management

My goal is to decide whether my application has a battery issue or not so I want to add a module that checking the percentage of my app battery usage each interval time.

**How can I retrieve the values of the battery usage for each application (or at least my application) by percentage?**
I saw several answers in stack overflow saying that there is no way...

Can I do something? even reflection is good for me.

Besides, is there any **good** dev tool that could help me investigate my app battery consumption? (by components, i.e. wifi, gps, gsm etc.)

thanks

Comment: This article could help: http://ziyang.eecs.umich.edu/projects/powertutor/camera-ready.pdf and this is the source code for PowerTutor app: https://github.com/msg555/PowerTutor. But I'm searching for quick and easy solution, if exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download "Dr. Power" from Android Market.
This app has been developed by a company that has the exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

The author of [BatteryIndicator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicator&hl=en) wrote in his [FAQ-How_does_Battery_Indicator_work?](http://code.google.com/p/battery-indicator/wiki/FAQ#How_does_Battery_Indicator_work?_/_How_does_it_know_what_percent)

> How does Battery Indicator work? / How does it know what percentage
>   the battery is at?
>
> The Android system has a mechanism where you can register your app to
>   be notified when the battery status changes. So Battery Indicator has
>   a background service that is technically always running but is
>   essentially always sleeping and using basically no system resources
>   (because it doesn't do any polling -- it just sleeps and waits to be
>   notified by the OS when something changes), then when the battery
>   charge (or plugged-in status) changes, the system wakes it up and
>   tells it what the new battery charge (and status) is. Then it takes
>   just a few milliseconds to change its icon to reflect the current
>   charge (and status) and goes back to sleep.
>
> If you're technically oriented, the documentation for the core API
>   that Battery Indicator uses is here:
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html
>   and the actual source code to the development version of the app is
>   here: http://code.google.com/p/battery-indicator/source/browse/trunk .

The app shows consumption of different modules

```
 Phone in Standby 59%
 Akku in Standby 39%
 Display 4%
```

But i donot know how this is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I retrieve the values of the battery usage for each application (or at least my application) by percentage?

There is nothing in the Android SDK for this, sorry.

> Besides, is there any good dev tool that could help me investigate my app battery consumption? (by components, i.e. wifi, gps, gsm etc.)

Buy a Qualcomm MDP and use Trepn. Unfortunately, this is expensive.

Comment: Man I knew that there is nothing in the SDK, that's why I asked my question, maybe a reflection solution will work

Comment: @Bush: I looked into that once, and I do not see where you can possibly get to battery-related stuff via reflection, even if that were a good idea. I filed an enhancement request related to this about 2.5 years ago: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4346